# Generic detail view must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: python, django, django-views

Django is giving me the following error when I try to access `/domains/{domain}/{host}`:

```
Generic detail view HostDetailPageView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
```

It appears that `DetailView` is expecting something different than what I am providing.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('domains/', DomainsPageView.as_view()),
    path('domains/<str:domain>', DomainHostsPageView.as_view()),
    path('domains/<str:domain>/<str:host>', HostDetailPageView.as_view()),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="hosts/index.html"))
]
```

**views.py**

```
class HostDetailPageView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'hosts/hostdetail.html'
    model = Host

    # Populates list of enabled domains in the context
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        filtered = qs.filter(name=self.kwargs['host'])

        if not filtered.exists():
            raise Http404("Host does not exist")

        # filter by a variable captured from url, for example
        return filtered.first()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

**models.py**

```
class Host(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=settings.MAX_CHAR_COUNT)
    ip_addresses = models.ManyToManyField(IPAddress)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    os = models.ForeignKey(OperatingSystem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    ciphers = models.ManyToManyField(Cipher, blank=True)
    certificate = models.ForeignKey(Certificate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

Comment: Can you add the `Host` and its related models?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I added the Host model definition

Comment: @ArakkalAbu My goal is to have the URL look like `/domains/example.com/host.example.com`

Comment: In which field the value of *host name* is stored?

Comment: In the urlpattern, it would be the last value `<str:host>`.   In the `Host` model, it is called `name`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Actually I meant "domain". In Domain model, in which field the value of "domain" stored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the **`pk_url_kwarg`** attribute and override the **`get_queryset(...)`** method of the view

```
class HostDetailPageView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'hosts/hostdetail.html'
    model = Host
    pk_url_kwarg = 'name'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(host__name=self.kwargs['host'])
```